# When attempting to change edit mode for a telerik grid to anything other than 'InLine' I get an error about passing in the wrong model type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

I create the grid like so:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid<myapp.Date>("dates")
    .Name("MyGrid")
    .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(10))
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.id))
    .DataBinding(dataBinding =>
    {
        dataBinding.Ajax()
        .Select("_SelectAjaxEditing", "Dates")
        .Insert("_InsertAjaxEditing", "Dates")
        .Update("_SaveAjaxEditing", "Dates")
        .Delete("_DeleteAjaxEditing", "Dates");
    })
    .ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert())
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.name);
        columns.Bound(o => o.date1);
        columns.Command(commands =>
        {
            commands.Edit().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
            commands.Delete().ButtonType(GridButtonType.Text);
        });
    })
    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
    .Render();
    %>
```

and it runs fine, but if I change the GridEditMode to be anything other than InLine I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'myapp.Date', but
>   this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'.

There is a system.DateTime field in the grid, is that the reason for this error?

Comment: how does your model look like? it seems like you are passing `DateTime` to the method that expects `DateTime?`

Comment: To try to answer this question, it would be helpful to see your relevant code from the controller and the model.

Comment: Without the model or controller this becomes a bit tricky. Have you tried either setting this DateTime field as nullable, or decorating it with [Required]?

Comment: @CarlB I tried remaking the model and giving it a name other than date (I called it ZeDate), same model, same table, same everything, except different name. And it worked without any problems. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is because the date you are passing as model is not nullable, while the date required to model is nullable, try this after changing the model type to "DATETIME?".

Note: If you are declaring property declare it as **DateTime?** as your field is nullable.

Thanks

Regards,

Dhaval Shukla